# Why does this program get a ClassNotFound Exception?

Tags: java, swing, serialization, classnotfoundexception

I need this simple virtual bank program to deserialize a main account each time it is started. I've done this, but the GUI class that runs this method continues to give me a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`. I'm not sure what my error is or how to fix it, what should I do? I'll post both classes below, as I'm not sure where the error can be found.

BankGUI class:

```
package GUIs;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

import virtualBank3.BankAccount;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BankGUI implements Serializable {

    BankAccount account;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BankGUI gui = new BankGUI();
        gui.deserializeAccount();
        gui.displayGUI();
    }

    // all global components for JFrame
    JTextArea statusArea;
    JCheckBox isLockedCheckBox;
    JList depositAmount;
    JList withdrawAmount;
    JButton depositButton;
    JButton withdrawButton;
    JButton saveAccountButton;

    private void displayGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Virtual Bank v3.3");

        Integer[] intList = { 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 150, 250, 500 };

        JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
        rightPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(rightPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        rightPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        centerPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        frame.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, centerPanel);
        frame.add(BorderLayout.EAST, rightPanel);

        // add some JLabel's
        JLabel depositAmountLabel = new JLabel("Deposit Amount:");
        JLabel withdrawAmountLabel = new JLabel("Withdraw Amount:");
        JLabel isLockedLabel = new JLabel("Lock account(True/False)");

        // finish components(center panel)
        statusArea = new JTextArea(15, 22);
        statusArea.setEditable(false);
        // add this to panel
        isLockedCheckBox = new JCheckBox();
        // add this to panel


        // scrollers and Jlists
        //***********************************************************************
        depositAmount = new JList(intList);
        JScrollPane scroller1 = new JScrollPane(depositAmount);
        scroller1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scroller1.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        depositAmount.setVisibleRowCount(1);
        depositAmount.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);


        withdrawAmount = new JList(intList);
        JScrollPane scroller2 = new JScrollPane(depositAmount);
        scroller2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scroller2.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        depositAmount.setVisibleRowCount(1);
        depositAmount.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        //***********************************************************************

        depositButton = new JButton("Deposit Amount.");
        withdrawButton = new JButton("Withdraw Amount");
        saveAccountButton = new JButton("Save your Account");

        frame.setSize(425, 650);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void serializeAccount() {
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream objectStream1 = new ObjectOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream("bankAccounts.txt"));
            objectStream1.writeObject(account);
            objectStream1.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void deserializeAccount() {
        try {
            ObjectInputStream objectStream2 = new ObjectInputStream(
                    new FileInputStream("bankAccounts.txt"));
            account = (BankAccount) objectStream2.readObject();
            objectStream2.close();
            //test it
            System.out.println("It worked.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

BankAccount Class:

```
package virtualBank3;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class BankAccount implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5341449653011848470L;

    int balance = 0;
    int userWallet = 0;
    String owner = "Hello, world";
    String accountStat = "Account Owner: " + owner + "\nAccount balance: $"
            + balance + "\nOwner Wallet Balance: $" + userWallet;
    Boolean isLocked = false;

    public int withdraw(int amount) {
        balance -= amount;
        userWallet += amount;
        return userWallet;
    }

    public int deposit(int amount) {
        balance += amount;
        userWallet -= amount;
        return balance;
    }

    public int depositCashIntoWallet(int amount) {
        userWallet += amount;
        return userWallet;
    }


}
```

Here's the error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: virtualBank3.Account
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at GUIs.BankGUI.deserializeAccount(BankGUI.java:123)
    at GUIs.BankGUI.main(BankGUI.java:40)
```

Comment: can you post the complete stacktrace?

Comment: Copy/paste the exception stack trace as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16297064/edit).  They are provided for good reasons!

Comment: Can you please paste the full stack trace?

Comment: BTW, why `Boolean isLocked = false;` and not the primitive `boolean`?

Comment: @Drogba Added the stack trace.

Comment: have you added the class BankAccount in classpath as well?

Comment: Could you tell us which class compiler is unable to detect. 
When you see the expection, it also tells about the class which it doesn't find. Eg., `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class-name-here`

Comment: @Satya What does that even mean?

Comment: is class Account present under virtualBank3 package?

Comment: No, but I imported it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Well, obviously. It's in the stack trace.

Comment: @HashSlingingHacker HAve you changed the classname from Account to BankAccount and serialised data? Then when trying to re-read the serialised data, it's looking for an Account class (which no longer exists). Is this possible? Where do you have a virtualBank3.Account class?

Comment: What is this Account class? You only show BankAccount, which doesn't have any relationship with any Account class. Where does thic Account class come from? How did you serialize it?

Comment: I can't see your Account class.

Comment: @wmorrison365 The class name was changed a long time ago. Why do you keep talking about the `Account` class? It doesn't exist.

Comment: @HashSlingingHacker He's talking about the Account class because the error in the stack-trace is caused by that.

Comment: It shouldn't exist. It was removed.

Comment: @HashSlingingHacker, as KPZ puts it, it's in your stack trace. It is deserializing your data but finding an "Account.class" serialized object. You've since changed your code to use BankAccount so the class no longer exists. I'd delete all serialized files to ensure they're serialized using your BankAccount class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a naming issue - you have a `public class virtualBank3.BankAccount`, but the serialized file refers to a `virtualBank3.Account`. Did you write the serialized file, or was it given to you? If the former, you renamed a class but didn't recreate the serialized file.

Comment: I wrote this, and I'm really confused. I changed the names a long time ago to avoid confusion with a previous class. I'm not sure why you guys think that `Account` is a problem. It doesn't exist.

Comment: The problem is that Account does not exist, but it's still referenced in the serialized file; the deserialization code looks into the file to determine class names to load, and doesn't find the required class, hence the ClassNotFound errror.

Comment: Re-create your bankAccounts.txt file.

Answer (score 2):

As per my comments above which are now lost in the trail:

@HashSlingingHacker HAve you changed the classname from Account to BankAccount and serialised data? Then when trying to re-read the serialised data, it's looking for an Account class (which no longer exists). Is this possible? Where do you have a virtualBank3.Account class?

As KPZ puts it, Account.class is referenced in your stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: virtualBank3.Account
```

It is deserializing your data but finding an "Account.class" serialized object. You've since changed your code to use BankAccount so the class no longer exists. I'd delete all serialized files to ensure they're serialized using your BankAccount class.

Comment: I deleted my bankAccounts.txt and then 'jumped' my project using my serializeAccount method. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are working on eclipse. And I guess you have rename your **class** `Account` to `BankAccount`.

Try:

- delete bankAccounts.txt
- clean projects(Project -> Clean... -> Clean all projects)
- run your project again

Answer (score 1):

Just do this

Project--->clean--->clean all projects

Because you rename your class Account to BankAccount